# How to do authenticated https access from perl

Tags: linux, perl, http, networking

What is the easiest/best way to access an https address requiring username/password and just check the HTTP response (if it is 3xx/4xx/5xx)?

Is it possible to do it without installing extra modules?
The idea behind this is just to do a health check (automatic) to an internal server. The page requires username/password which I have

Comment: https doesn't have username/password. Those are different things. Are you talking about basic auth?

Comment: @simbabque:Yes exactly that

Comment: Sounds like you want to bruteforce your way into something...

Comment: @simbabque: Just want to do a "health" check to an internal server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it out of the box, you can just use [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) and create your own [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) object, which has an [`authorization_basic` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers#h-authorization_basic). It's a bit hard to find in the documentation. It comes from [HTTP::Message](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Message), which [says it delegates some methods](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Message#COPYRIGHT) to [HTTP::Headers](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers).

> All methods unknown to HTTP::Message itself are delegated to the HTTP::Headers object that is part of every message. This allows convenient access to these methods. Refer to HTTP::Headers for details of these methods

For coveniance you may use [HTTP:Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $req = GET 'https://www.example.org';
$req->authorization_basic('user', 'password');

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->request($req);

print $res->code;
```

**Output:**

```
200
```

If you are not interested in the content, maybe a HEAD request is enough. That will save some time as no body is sent over the network.

```
my $req = HEAD 'https://www.example.org';
```

Comment: You can also use the IO::Socket::SSL configuration that [xxfelixxx shows in their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32112952/1331451).

Answer (score 2):

Try using [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::SSL;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    # Need ssl_opts if trying to get past an invalid certificate...
    ssl_opts => {
        SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
        verify_hostname => 0,
    },
    # Do not die if the page fetch fails
    autocheck => 0,  
);

# user, password
$mech->credentials( 'robot_user', 'r0B07_U$3r_p4$$\/\/0rD' );

$mech->get("https://foo.bar.baz.com/secret_url.html");
if ($mech->success) {
    print "==> SUCCESS\n";
    print $mech->content();
} else {
    print "==> FAILURE\n";
    print "HTTP STATUS [ " . $mech->status . " ]\n";
}
```

Comment: Maybe a HEAD request works here, that might be a bit faster because there is no body. Also using Parallel::ForkManager could speed stuff up.

Comment: How do I know what kind of response was it? Can I do without adding a library?